# Stevia Plant, aka. Sweetleaf, Sugarleaf, Sweet Herb - where to get seeds?

Tags: herbs, seeds

Stevia Plants, to be precise their leaves are being used as a natural sugar substitute in some countries like Japan, India and over South American for decades or centuries now.

Especially in the European Union, Stevia was only lately approved (December, 2011) by the WHO for human consumption, after several evaluations for toxicity and Long-Term Health Effects.
[More information here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevia).

**Q**: Where can I buy Stevia seeds?! It seems, after several approaches to get my hands on the seeds, that i either asked the wrong people, they never heard about it or couldn't point me in the right direction. Right now I live in Frankfurt, but anyway online resellers are just fine with me!

Also, if anyone of you is experienced, in growing this particular plant from seeds, feel free to give me some advice of how to do it right.

Comment: Those seeds are very tiny. I use a mist, in the shade, to start them, on the surface of peat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stevia seems to be widely available in North America.  Examples include [Vesey's](http://www.veseys.com/ca/en/store/herbs/steviatp/stevia) or [Richters](http://www.richters.com/Web_store/web_store.cgi?product=X6030&show=all&prodclass=&cart_id=1193093.31991)

The issue seems to be that plants grown from seed can have [widely varying amounts](http://www.stevia.net/growingstevia.htm) of the sugar substitute. Seeds can normally be shipped across the world but live plants are subject to phytosanitary certificates which are a lot of work for an individual.  Your best choice would seem to be growing from seed and selecting for the sweetest leaves.  You can grow them indoors but an plot of well drained soil with rich loam will give the best results

Comment: Thank you for your fast and sufficient reply and sukevinsky! That raises another question of different nature!

Answer (score 5):

I order most of my seeds from Baker Creek Heirloom Seeds. They have [stevia](http://rareseeds.com/stevia.html).

Answer (score 3):

I purchased some from Paraguay but have yet to see them sprout, I got a TON of seeds so I will try again. Surprisingly enough, I also saw them at Lowes, but when I shook the little seed packet I could tell they were a completely different type of seed. I'd check out the ones at Lowes or buy from a reputable seed company like Parkseed. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

[Johnny Seeds](http://www.johnnyseeds.com) has stevia seeds, product 2305. The might even have organic seeds too, but that's not the same as heritage seeds either.